# Compact Embeddings of the space of continuous functions

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces and assume $\iota:X \hookrightarrow Y$ is a compact linear injection. Let $K$ be a compact topological space (the unit interval if that helps). Then the space $C(K,X)$ of continuous functions $K \to X$ is a Banach space as well. Is it true that the operator $C(K,X) \to C(K,Y)$, $f \mapsto \iota \circ f$, is compact as well?

Certainly, if $(f^{(j)})_{j \in N}$ is a sequence bounded in $C(K,X)$, then for any $k \in K$, the sequence $(f^{(j)}(k))_{j \in N}$ is bounded in $X$. Hence, $\iota(f^{(j)}(k))$ contains a subsequence converging to some $y \in Y$. This defines a map $f:K \to Y$. But I am unable to show that $f^{(j)} \to f$ in $C(K,Y)$. Maybe one needs some additional assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the operator induced by $\iota$ has no reason to be compact. For a simple counterexample consider $X = Y$ finite-dimensional, and $\iota$ the identity, then the induced map $C(K,X) \to C(K,Y)$ is also the identity, and that is compact only if $C(K,X)$ is finite-dimensional, which is not the case for most $K$.